# Why the jquery method is not working inside some div with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="tab-content" id="allResults"></div>
```

I am changing content of this div via javascript and it contains one button as

```
<a href="#" id="popover" data-toggle="popover" onclick = "displayMessage(this)" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top" data-content="Email the report!"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="color:green"></span></a>
```

This popover doesn't show up while inside this div but the same thing works fine outside this div. what might be the reason?

I am using this jquery method to display the popover :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? `popover` isn't a method in jQuery, are you using an additional library?

Comment: I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Perhaps you can put together a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) showing the problem you're having.

Comment: Bootstrap popover isn't 'inside' the div. Check the html [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) and you'll see it is appended to the end of the body (EDIT: in v3 it's appended after the button or the a tag)

Comment: I am displaying the hundreds of search results inside the div where on portion of code for each search result contains this :
<a href="#"  data-toggle="popover" ..........></span></a>, but unfortunately its not working.
 PS: it works outside this div.

Comment: Ah you mean the popover inside 'tab-content' div don't work? Please edit your question and add a [mcve] or a fiddle as per Andrea's suggestion. We need to know what you are doing. You are dynamically adding those elements. Are you doing the same for the popovers outside that div?

Comment: I think I will not be able to add codes on fiddle (will try though), but yeah, like you said I am dynamically adding those elements but not same for the popovers outside that div.

Comment: I suspected that's the issue. You need to use event delegation, because the elements don't exist yet when setting up .popover()

Comment: Go to the popover docs then carefully read what it says at the 'selector' option and in the example they provide: https://jsbin.com/zopod/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements you need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). The bootstrap popover provides a way to do it by adding the element as an option.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  '$('body').popover({
     selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'
   });  
});
```

BTW, do NOT create duplicate `id`s for your elements.